# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol on build with gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dagger, butterknife

I'm using Android Studio and when I try to build my project with gradle I'm getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol
```

It started to happen when I changed Butterknife from 5.1.2 to 7.0.1

In my dependencies I also have Dagger (1.2.2)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What I found out after lot's of find/replace is that when dagger was doing it's magic on the build step, and there still was any wrong annotations (still using `@InjectView` or `@Optional`) or missing import (from the annotations `@Bind` or `@Nullable`) it would throw the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$VarSymbol
```

The solution is to fix all imports and wrong annotations.